# Issue with FMTONLY in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I support an application that uses CodeSmith and NetTiers templates to generate C# code. CodeSmith inspects the database and uses the `SET FMTONLY ON` setting to determine the columns for which code should be generated.

Unfortunately in moving from SQL Server 2005 to 2012 there is a particular circumstance where this is now no longer working. There is a Stored Procedure that executes a Stored Procedure on a linked server and the code being generated for that Stored Procedure is incorrect.

I've managed to isolate the issue to the `EXEC` statement with `SET FMTONLY ON`. The following (example only) `SELECT` works on both the 2005 and 2012 instances:

```
SET FMTONLY ON
SELECT TOP(10) [MCMCU]
              ,[MCSTYL]
              ,[MCDC]
FROM [JDE].[JDE_CRP].[CRPDTA].[F0006]
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

This returns the column headings only, as expected. The following works only on the 2005 instance:

```
SET FMTONLY ON
EXEC('SELECT TOP(10) [MCMCU]
                    ,[MCSTYL]
                    ,[MCDC]
      FROM [JDE_CRP].[CRPDTA].[F0006]') AT [JDE]
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

When run on the 2012 instance, SSMS shows the message "Command(s) completed successfully" but doesn't display the column headings.

Is there anything I'm missing here? Perhaps a setting that I need to change? The linked server definitions are identical, including the identity used to connect. And yes I'm aware that `FMTONLY` is deprecated but I don't have any ability to change the way CodeSmith interrogates the database.

Comment: What if you also add SET inside the exec()? What if you try sp_executesql instead of exec()?

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I tried `sp_executesql`. The behaviour was slightly different but didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: what about my other suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce that same behavior on SQL Server 2012. However, I am able to get it to work by putting the Linked Server name back into the query. Is there a reason you moved it out into the `AT` clause?

Try the following:

```sql
SET FMTONLY ON
EXEC('SELECT TOP(10) [MCMCU]
                    ,[MCSTYL]
                    ,[MCDC]
      FROM [JDE].[JDE_CRP].[CRPDTA].[F0006]');
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

---

Well, while the above does work on SQL Server 2012, it was not a good test because it does not work when executing a stored procedure. It might have something to do with it being a different type of call (i.e. the stored procedure call is RPC, and that had to be configured separately).

I even just tried adding `WITH RESULT SETS ((...))` and that still didn't work.

---

Ok, so I found something. It is generally known that `FMTONLY ON` doesn't actually run the code, it just scans it for `SELECT` statements. But, that also means that it doesn't know how to handle conditional code. So it returns whatever result sets *could be* returned, even if no code path would ever return some of them.

Example 1 has two `SELECT` statements, but only one can ever be returned at a time. Still, when running with `FMTONLY ON`, both are returned:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FmtOnlyTest1
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @A INT = 5;

  IF (@A <> 6)
  BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [master].[sys].[objects];
  END;
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @A) + N' AS [IntVal];'
    EXEC(@SQL);
END;
GO
```

Results:

```sql
-- Running normally returns one result set of 5 rows from sys.objects:
EXEC Test.dbo.FmtOnlyTest1;

-- With FMTONLY ON, it returns two result sets: one from sys.objects AND one with [IntVal]
SET FMTONLY ON
EXEC Test.dbo.FmtOnlyTest1;
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

Example 2 shows another consequence of not being able to run the code. If the code produces the result set dynamically, it cannot be determined by `FMTONLY ON`. This probably explains why it can't follow the EXEC call when the code is remote. I suspect that calling local Stored Procedures works by just doing a lookup in the local system catalog table for that definition.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FmtOnlyTest2
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @A INT;

  SELECT TOP 1 @A = [object_id] FROM sys.objects;

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
  SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @A) + N' AS [IntVal];'
  EXEC(@SQL);
GO
```

Results:

```sql
-- Running normally returns one result set of just [IntVal];
EXEC Test.dbo.FmtOnlyTest2;

-- With FMTONLY ON, there are no result sets returned (just like with the remote procedure)
SET FMTONLY ON
EXEC Test.dbo.FmtOnlyTest2;
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

Knowing what we now know, we can use the fact that `FMTONLY ON` will find all result sets while not actually running the code to, even if not ideal, fake a result set to get CodeSmith (and other tools that still work in this fashion) working again.

Example 3 shows that we can effectively hide a dummy result set in a code block that cannot logically execute. Only `FMTONLY ON` will be able to see this so it won't present a problem for any other code (well, I did try `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` and that didn't really like it, but I don't think that is an issue in this case).

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FmtOnlyTest3
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF (1 = 0)
  BEGIN
    SELECT CONVERT(INT, NULL) AS [FieldName1],
           CONVERT(DATETIME, NULL) AS [FieldName2];
  END;

  DECLARE @A INT;

  SELECT TOP 1 @A = [object_id] FROM sys.objects;

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
  SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @A) + N' AS [IntVal];'
  EXEC(@SQL);
GO
```

Results:

```sql
-- Running normally returns one result set of just [IntVal];
EXEC Test.dbo.FmtOnlyTest3;

-- Running with FMTONLY ON returns one result set of [FieldName1], [FieldName2]
SET FMTONLY ON
EXEC Test.dbo.FmtOnlyTest3;
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

For this test I had the code return a different result set for the `IF (1 = 0)` block to make the difference in behavior more apparent. But in practice, you would want to return the exact same result set structure in the `SELECT` as the remote stored procedure returns.

The obvious down-side here is that if you change the result set of that remote procedure you will have to remember to also change the definition in the `IF (1 = 0)` block, but at least CodeSmith will function.

Comment: I also think placing the FTMONLY statement *inside* the EXEC() would work.

Comment: Aaron that might work but I don't have any control over where the `SET FMTONLY ON` is placed. It is executed by the CodeSmith tool.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I highly doubt that either `EXEC()` or `sp_executesql` is involved in the actual operation here. I believe the EXEC was used for demo purposes. CodeSmith should just be executing the proc as it normally would and knows nothing of the Linked Server.

Comment: @DavidClarke Am I correct about what I just replied to Aaron with regarding CodeSmith? You were just using EXEC() in the question to get the overall point across, right? As opposed to that being exactly what CodeSmith was doing?

Comment: @srutzky In fairness, I'm commenting on the specific code in the question, which is what other readers will come across as well, not some different thing that the OP hasn't explained.

Comment: @srutzky no CodeSmith does actually `EXEC()` the stored proc with `SET FMTONLY ON`. It uses the output, i.e. the list of columns, to determine which template to use to generate the source. The issue with the move to SQL Server 2012 was that the output from that stored procedure no longer returned the list of columns so the method generated returned `void` instead of `DataSet`. It may well be that a newer version of CodeSmith uses the new options.

Comment: @DavidClarke Are you saying that CodeSmith adds a literal `EXEC()` call around the proc? So that it is running `EXEC(dbo.ProcName);`? Or is it just doing a regular RPC call of the proc from app code, but using `FMTONLY ON` to get the result set schema without actually executing it? Usually it is the later. There is no reason for it to add in an extra `EXEC()` layer. In fact, it is quite easy to set `FMTONLY ON` and EXEC a stored procedure from .NET code by using the `CommandBehavior`s of `SqlCommand`, which is what I suspect CodeSmith is doing.

Comment: I was using the profiler to see what was going on and it shows the `SET FMTONLY ON` followed by `EXEC()` with all parameters NULL, and finally a `SET FMTONLY OFF`

Comment: @DavidClarke What does it show during normal operation? Does it still have the EXEC? If I get time I will profile from a simple .NET app using the appropriate CommandBehavior to see how it shows up. However, I believe it's all a moot point since I tested by calling `SET FMTONLY ON; EXEC Test.dbo.RemoteTest; SET FMTONLY OFF;` where that proc has in it an EXEC of a proc across a Linked Server. It returns no result set at all, even using `WITH RESULT SETS`. The issue here has to do with changes made in 2012. I ran into this 3 years ago going from 2005 to 2012 with OPENQUERY. But we had no fix :(.

Comment: Right, that issue came up a lot in my search results. To be honest I haven't looked at what it does under normal operation - I will need to check. Thanks for the heads up.